# How to send information, by POST method in a hidden form?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have the following code, which shows me the records of people from a query. I want to send through the post function the id_Persona by a hidden form, and send to page idsPersonas.php just caching the id_Persona

I did this way:

```
<tr class='clickable-row' onclick="post('/idsPersonas.php/',{ids: <?php "$lista[id_Persona];" ?>});">
```

and send me to undefined page

this is my code:

```
         <table id="example" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                    <thead class="text-primary">
                        <tr >

                            <th class="cabezera"><center><h4>Fecha</h4></center></th>
                            <th class="cabezera"><center><h4>Hora</h4></center></th>
                            <th class="cabezera"><center><h4>Nombre</h4></center></th>

                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                        <?php
                            if(count($listado)> 0 ){
                                foreach($listado as $lista) 
                            {
                            $cuenta++;              
                        ?> 
                    <tbody>

                        <tr class='clickable-row' onclick="post('/idsPersonas.php/',{ids: <?php "$lista[id_Persona];" ?>});">

                            <td><?php printf("%s",$lista["Fecha"]);  ?></td>
                            <td><?php printf("%s",$lista["Hora"]);  ?></td>
                            <td><?php printf("%s",$lista["Nombre"]);  ?></td>

                        </tr> 
                        <?php     
                            }
                                }else {
                        ?> 
                        <h3> No hay </h3>
                        <?php
                            }//fin else 
                            //printf($cuenta_eventos);  
                        ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

JS:

```
function post(path, params, method) {
    method = method || "post"; // Set method to post by default if not specified.
    console.log(method);

// The rest of this code assumes you are not using a library.
// It can be made less wordy if you use one.
var form = document.createElement("form");
form.setAttribute("method", method);
form.setAttribute("action", path);

for(var key in params) {
    if(params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
        hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
        hiddenField.setAttribute("name", key);
        hiddenField.setAttribute("value", params[key]);

        form.appendChild(hiddenField);
     }
}

document.body.appendChild(form);
form.submit();
}
```

Comment: `post('/idsPersonas.php/',` Remove the second `/`

Comment: sending you to undefined page because "/idsPersonas.php/" cannot be found. Remove the last slash as Patrick Q suggested and you may have to remove the first slash also if idsPersonas.php is not in the root of your web path. Basically you do not need slashes to escape.... do you need slashes in your path?

Comment: @NawedKhan i remove the slashes, and still the problem undefined and in my console log shows _uncaught syntaxerror unexpected token }_

Comment: what URL is shown on address bar when this undefined page error shows... is that a valid url?

Comment: The variable `<?php "$lista[id_Persona];" ?>` shows what exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You put the quotation marks in the wrong places.
It should read like this:

```
{ids: '<?php echo $lista['id_Persona']; ?>'});">
```